# Echo text if value of variable equals zero

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this code:

```
<?php
if ( $amount < 5 ) {
  echo 'Credit Balance low! You have';
  echo $amount;
  echo ' remaining credits.';
} else {
  echo 'No recent alerts...';
}
?>
```

Where it says `echo $amount;` I want to `echo $00.00` if the value of `$amount == 0`. How would I include this in my code?

Comment: What does it do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if ( $amount < 5 )
{
    echo 'Credit Balance low! You have';
    echo $amount == 0 ? '$00.00' : $amount;
    echo ' remaining credits.';
}
else
{
    echo 'No recent alerts...';
}
?>
```

Comment: if I could un-accept this myself I would. I'll award a +1 to cletus for correctness.

Answer (score 6):

```
echo $amount === 0 ? '$00.00' : $amount;
```

?

Answer (score 6):

You're probably looking for the [money_format() function](https://www.php.net/money_format).

```
<?php echo money_format('%=0-2', $amount); ?>
```

`=0` fills with the `0` character, and `-2` left-justifies to a minimum field width of 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($amount === 0) {
    echo '$0.00';
} elseif ($amount < 5) {
    echo "Credit Balance low! You have $amount remaining credits";
} else {
    echo 'No recent alerts...';
}
```

Comment: You have a rogue echo in the middle part - it should probably be `echo 'Credit Balance low! You have ', $amount, ' remaining credits';`

Comment: `echo 'Credit Balance low! You have ', $amount, ' remaining credits';` is also the fastest way of echoing that line.

Comment: @Dan: If it's faster, it's negligible and not even worth mentioning. I'm pretty sure most people would prefer the more readable double quote version.

Comment: @ryeguy - using vars in double quotes in itself is overhead (doubles are slower than single quotes because the WHOLE string has to be parsed for a var) as well as multiple calls. Sure, it's not a huge difference but isn't that what best practice is all about? Isn't it not worth pointing out to those interested? Too, for readability, I personally find vars shoved in quotes hard to find when reviewing code. 'text label for ', $myVar makes myVar easy to spot. Also, what about when arrays are used? $data['object']['label'] - why mix up encoding styles of double quotes with vars to concatenation?

Comment: @Dan: I've done timings a while ago, and NO there isn't any performance penalty. Using decent text editor/IDE would let you *spot* your variable with ease. In case of array elements, it might be more beneficial to use string concatenation, but in this particular case the best practice would be to leave the variable in double quotes.

Comment: In the interest of healthy debate :) http://fusionswift.com/2010/05/php-concatenation-benchmark-comma-vs-period/ - And yes, i know it's over a gagillion tries :/ I just felt if worth mentioning, i still +1'd the answer :p  (and i know editors display the var, i suppose my brain just has a better time with them outside quotes so that way if there is anyone on here with crazy brains like me, they'll have a tip heh heh)

Comment: @Dan: You can still parse objects and arrays inside of quotes if you wrap them in curly braces.

Comment: Yeah, it's all the readability thing for me - but this is good, I think anyone stumbling on this post is going to find out the four hundred ways to output data, lol

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
<?php 

if ($amount === 0) {
  echo '$00.00';
}
elseif ($amount < 5 && $amout > 0) {
  echo 'Credit Balance low! You have' . $amount . ' remaining credits.';
}
else {
  echo 'No recent alerts...';
}    

?>
```